# How to get value of NSTextField dynamic add to NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nstextfield

I have a Combobox contains 30 items (1,2,...,30). I want to select item in Combobox, create dynamic NSTextField same item selected in Combobox. Then user input text to NSTextField, and then click on button to get all text of each NSTextField add to NSMutableArray.
I use bellow code to get text from NSTextField and add it to Array but it can only get from 1 NSTextField:

```
NSMutableArray * SSID_Arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:x];
[SSID_Arr addObject:ssidtxt.stringValue]; // get text from NSTextField
NSLog (@"SSID_Arr : %@",SSID_Arr);

NSString *strSSID;
for(int j=0; j < [SSID_Arr count]; j++)
{
    strSSID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\nSSID : %@", [SSID_Arr objectAtIndex:j]];
}
```

Do you have suggestion? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

just make

```
NSMutableArray *SSID_Arr = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray * SSID_Arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:x];
```

gives an array with space reserved for x values.But **there is no value in that position right now**

So first fill up the array via a loop and then continue as

```
NSMutableArray * SSID_Arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:x];
for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
    [SSID_Arr addObject:ssidtxt.stringValue]; 
}
```

Now the array contains x values and you can proceed.Please note the one textfield value is getting populated here x times.If you have to store all textfield values ,write a loop suitable to achieve all values and add it

Comment: Thanks, but your code is can only get text from 1 ssidtxt. If i have many ssidtxt???

Comment: you can get it one by one via outlet or set tag to the views and get the view in reference with tags and use it

Comment: I create textfield dynamic, how can i get tag for it?